How can resolve the crash af all my jetbrains logiciel?
I work with Android Studio and Intellij and since 1 month they started to crash just like that.When i open one of them, if I use it or not but it opens, it crashes after few min creating a log file in my folder C:\Users\HP.I uninstalled them but it's always same.the worst thing is i made a lot of manipulation to try to find a solution and sometimes it worked but after some days they restart to crash so i understand that what i did wasn't the solution.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/DKfeSn4E.jpg)  here a part of the content of the log file created after crashing

Do you have any plugins? Have you tried updating them? Or turning them off? Are you using Jetbrains toolbox to install your apps? If not, give it a try.

Does it help by "add -Dsun.java2d.metal=false in Help | Edit Custom VM Options and restart the IDE."?

I tried  -Dsun.java2d.metal=false and it doesn't work for me. And No i have no plugins, beside as I said i uninstalled Intellij and Android studio several times . I even tried with intellij community but nothing
